# RSA: If I know n, e, p, and q, how do I calculate d using the extended euclidean algorithm?

Tags: rsa

After doing a good amount of research, it's become fairly obvious that I ought to be using the extended Euclidean algorithm to calculate d from the data that I already have.

However, this isn't an area of mathematics I'm very familiar with, and the algorithm both takes and outputs multiple integers instead of just one.

So, my question is: Which of the numbers that I already have to I need to input into the algorithm, and of the several numbers it outputs, which is the one I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes it's the common way. And formally $d=\frac{1}{e} \; mod \; lcm((p-1),(q-1))$

Comment: *"this isn't an area of mathematics I'm very familiar with"* Well, that's a problem because it's what RSA and most other popular cryptosystems today are all about. You will have to remedy this.